# How can I write to a .csv file multiple times and keep the previous data using C++?

Tags: c++, csv

As of now I am doing this:

```
std::ofstream file;
file.open("test.csv");
file << "Test case" << std::endl;
file.close()
```

The problem is the .csv file will get overwritten with new data, each time a programme is launched. So in this case each time I run the programme I would get one line of the text `"Test case"` instead of having this line added to the .csv file. Is there a way to keep the data consistent and just add them to the same file, while keeping the previous data, each time I run the programme?

Comment: Please have a look at the [std::fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) reference.

Comment: Most [good beginners books](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte#Character_classification) would have told you how to ***append*** to a file. Or actually *any* book (or tutorial) should have told you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a second parameter to open, for example `file.open("test.csv", ios_base::app)`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/filebuf/open/

Comment: Just to add that you can use mutiple parameters if you separate them with a `|` like `file.open("test.csv", ios_base::app | ios_base::out)`